# Chrome 57 & SVG code breaking changes

Tags: google-chrome, svg, transform

I was experimenting with SVG manipulations in the last few months and recently noticed that rotate and scale in my app became buggy.

See below the commented line for "var transform". That is how it used to work.
Now I realized that I can just do simple scale(number) and rotate(angle) in my app (see the non commented var transform line).

```
this.move = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    eventObj = isTouchSupported? event.touches[0] : event;
    var p = widget.services.globalToLocalCoordinates(eventObj.clientX, eventObj.clientY);
    var rdx = morphTarget.rotation.center.x - p.x;
    var rdy = morphTarget.rotation.center.y - p.y;
    var theta = 90 + Math.atan2(rdy, rdx) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var sdx = morphTarget.scale.point.x - p.x;
    var sdy = morphTarget.scale.point.y - p.y;
    var d = Math.sqrt(sdx * sdx + sdy * sdy);
    //var transform = "rotate(" + theta + " " + morphTarget.rotation.center.x + "," + morphTarget.rotation.center.y + ") translate(" + morphTarget.rotation.center.x + "," + morphTarget.rotation.center.y + ") scale(" + d / morphTarget.scale.height + ") translate(" + (-morphTarget.rotation.center.x) + "," + (-morphTarget.rotation.center.y) + ")";
    var transform = "rotate(" + theta +") scale(" + d / morphTarget.scale.height + ")";
    morphTarget.setAttribute("transform", transform);
    //this.target.setAttribute( "transform", transform);
}.bind(this);
```

So this new version does help to simplify the code, now the problem is - when after transforms I try to consolidate matrix and calculate absolute coordinates of verticies of my shape - that now acts weird;/

```
var matrix = this.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
        //console.log(matrix, this);
        for (i = 0; i < this.pathPoints.length; i++) {
            var position = this.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
            position.x = this.pathPoints["p" + i].x;
            position.y = this.pathPoints["p" + i].y;
            position = position.matrixTransform(matrix);
            this.pathPoints["p" + i].x = (position.x).toFixed(2);
            this.pathPoints["p" + i].y = (position.y).toFixed(2);
        };
        this.setAttribute("d", this.constructPath());
        this.setAttribute("transform", "matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)");
```

QUESTION:
how does one normally learns of such drastic code breaking changes coming for Chrome and if I notice that - how do I protect myself from such things to occur in future?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/beta.html

Comment: Feeling your pain today. Having an SVG issue just crop up that is only occurring on macOS Sierra Chrome 57, but not OS X El Capitan Chrome 57.